# Jenkins: Building multiple repos with different branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple repos with their own jenkins files and when I am working on one repo I will need to build the others so I have an end to end app deployed for feature development. As the app runs on AWS with the containers deployed into EKS my preference is to be able to build and run on AWS.

There is an order to the building, the infrastructure needs to deployed first, before the backend services (there are 3) and the UI.

Ideally I can choose which branches from the 5 repos are deployed, and when a change on any branch that is deployed as part of the ephemeral environment occurs the pipeline will trigger.

So far what I am thinking is to have a jenkinsfile in each repo and create a 6th repo, which will have just a yaml file and jenkinsfile of its own. This pipeline job for this repo would take data from the yaml file about which branches to use, and trigger the other pipelines passing the branch to each, it would be the only repo with an actual pipeline job.

Has anyone tried this? I'm not sure if it's possible to have a pipeline watch multiple different repos and branches and act as an orchestrator, kicking off other pipelines.

There might be a much easier way to do this, I have read a lot of posts and articles but none seem to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach can be writing single Jenkinsfile by combing all the stages from each repo into this single Jenkinsfile

```
stages {
  stage('Infra Setup') {
    steps {
      
      // The below will clone your repo and will be checked out to master branch by default.
      git credentialsId: 'jenkins_git_cred', url: '<your_git_url_for_clone>'
      sh "git checkout branchname"
      // Your steps 
    }
  }

  stage('Backend1 ') {
    steps {
     //If you want to checkout to a specific branch by default instead of master then use the below in your pipeline stage. 
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/branchname']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'jenkins_git_cred', url: 'your_git_url_for_clone']]])
    }
  }

  stage('backend_n') {
    steps {
      // One or more steps need to be included within the steps block.
    }
  }

  stage('UI') {
    steps {
      // One or more steps need to be included within the steps block.
    }
  }

}
```

You can generate syntax using jenkins pipeline-syntax
https://your-jenkins-url.com/pipeline-syntax/

Comment: Using this example, if a developer is working on `feature-A` in infra and then `feature-X` in `Backend1` would changes to either branch trigger this pipeline?

Comment: not in that case.